# how can I install office js using npm

Tags: office-js

I couldn't find way to install office js api using npm.

Can you please let us know the name of the office js package.

Currently I am referencing it from index.html thru this link
https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/Office.js

but I would like to add this as part of my web pack bundling.

Answer (score 3):

As an update:  the NPM package (as a reflection of the files on the CDN) is now available at https://www.npmjs.com/package/@microsoft/office-js, with all of the JS files in the `dist` folder.  The files are also available via a GitHub repo, which also offers a more extensive README:  https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js.

Answer (score 1):

The office-js npm package is close to being made available in beta mode starting with Excel. There is some more work to do for other hosts such as Word, OneNote, shared APIs, etc. It should be available [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@microsoft/office-js) in few days and we'll rev the same version with future updates.

Comment: thanks for the update Sudhi.This will help our build process.

Comment: Other people from MS said the CDN is the most recent built. Nuget, and probably, all packages won't be updated

Comment: Nugget is updated every 2-3 months. We are working making that more frequent. NPM package is only available for Excel on an experimental basis now.

Comment: It's a shame for microsoft not being able to publish their API via npm. Also the documentation is a shame. If they want developers use their products, they should make it easier for everyone. Instead, one has to search three days around to get started.